# How to read number of arguments - c++

Tags: c++, arguments

Usually in my code I need to use specific functions for various variables i.e.

```
object->SetStatus("var1",1); object->SetAddress("var1",&var1);
object->SetStatus("var2",1); object->SetAddress("var2",&var2);
object->SetStatus("var3",1); object->SetAddress("var3",&var3);
...
```

My idea is to use a function that will do this automatically by calling it, i.e.

```
object->function(var1,var2,var3,...);
```

To achieve that I have to solve 3 issues

1. I need to read the number of arguments when calling function()
2. I need to parse somehow the argument names inside the code
3. Since the variables are not of the same type, I need to find a way to make function() type "transparent"

Since I am newbie in c++ coding, I tried to search fo something similar, but I couldn't find anything.

Any help, advice or remark is more than welcome!

Comment: Ellipsis is the keyword you're looking for, but generally speaking, there are often better things you can do which avoid their use.

Comment: What application are you coding (some interpreter perhaps)? In C++11 or C++03? What is the type of `var1`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : I am coding in CERN's data analysis framework, which is called root. The types are `int`, `double` and `float`, numerical that is

Comment: The problem with ellipsis is that the called function has no way of knowing how many parameters were passed to it, which is what the OP was asking. You could add a count as the first/second argument or have a unique end-of-parameters value.

Comment: Also, what is 'function' doing? There may be a different way to approach this that is more C++.

Comment: @Skizz Actually `vari` is object's sub-object, So function will enable only the desired sub-objects and parse each value of `vari` to `vari`

Comment: But the arguments passed in the function are going to be variable names.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so. One way is make a `Base` class and all your variable type will inherit from this base class. Then pass a `map<string,Base>` as an argument to you function. name of variable will be key and value will be actual variables. Iterate through the map and set and assign values to methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider some [variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), if coding in C++11 or C++14. There is considerable literature about that subject (e.g. [this tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/)), which is a bit tricky (so explaining it here is not reasonable). Read also about [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

You could also use C style [varargs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)  using [`<cstdarg>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)

Perhaps [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/initializer_list) could be useful too.